# Retrieving malware report information from malware network

Tags: network, malware

I'm getting ready to stand up an isolated malware network at the place I work for performing analysis tasks and it will have a suite of reverse-engineering and analysis tools on it. For obvious reasons, this network is going to be disconnected from our normal business network. I have been trying to figure out, though - what is an appropriate way to retrieve screenshots, text, disassembly, etc. off of the malware network for when I want to present those things in reports? Is a separate computer with an antivirus scanner sufficient? I have been trying to find articles describing the sanitization process other people use but have not found any good resources.

Answer (score 2):

Learn more about sandbox environments, try [Cuckoo sandbox](https://www.cuckoosandbox.org/).
You can configure everything, so that it takes screenshots (which are not infected) and generate other information.